# second quantization lost particle number information?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, second-quantization

In first quantization, we can read the particle number from the Hamiltonian.

$$
H=\sum_{i=1}^N \hat{T}(x_i)
$$

Converting this to second quantization form, the particle number of the system is lost:

$$
H=\sum_{kk'} a_k^\dagger\left<k|\hat{T}|k'\right>a_{k'}
$$

Why do we see that the  they are equivalent? Is there any other thing lost in second quantization?

Comment: What is $\hat{T}$ in your equation? $H$ is usually reserved for the Hamiltonian (and $T$ almost always stands for the kinetic energy in this context). The particle number is $H=\sum_k a_k^\dagger a_k$. Nothing is lost.

Comment: @MengCheng $\hat{T}$ is kinetic energy. I mean we can not read off the particle number from the second quantized Hamiltonian.

Comment: Why would you even expect the Hamiltonian tell you the particle number in the first place? It is not supposed to.

Comment: The first quantized Hamiltonian does not really tell you the particle number. You put $N$ in by hand.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point in quantum field theory is that the number of particles is not fixed anymore, particles can be created and annihilated. The mean number of particles is a property of states, not of the Hamiltonian. States belong to a [Fock space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fock_space), that accommodates states with arbitrary number of identical particles. The mean number of particles in a given state $|\varphi\rangle$ is $$\langle N\rangle = \langle \varphi| \sum_k a_k^\dagger a_k |\varphi \rangle$$ If the number operator commutes with the Hamiltonian $[H,N]=0$, then the mean number of particles is conserved, and you can work in a subspace of constant $\langle N \rangle$.